# Resizing image in jumbotron How?

Tags: css

If someone could please be kind enough to help me out, it may seem dumb but im still learning things with bootstrap and just coding in general. Im wanting to fill my image in the jumbotron but if you take a look my image its not filling the whole jumbotron, not only that but i would also like to make it a little smaller

```
<body>
      <div class="container" id="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                  <ul class="nav justify-content-end p-4">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">THE ASAP ADVANTAGE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQS</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
            <img src="heroimage.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" id="heroPic">
     </div>
```

---css code is---

```
#header{
background-color: #004157;
height:120px;
width:100%;

}

#heroPic{
    opacity: .5;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: just add this property `width: 100%;height: 200px;` to `#heroPic`

Answer (score 0):

The `background-size` attribute only applies to images that are added through CSS as a `background-image`. For reference you can read about [background images here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) and [background sizing here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

Basically if you want to add the image as a background you could do something like this:

```
#heroPic{
    opacity: .5;
    background: url('heroimage.jpeg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Then in the HTML you would need to remove this line:

```
<img src="heroimage.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" id="heroPic">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok i appreciate it, if i remove the html line then where am i adding the image?

Comment: @Bharness913 you are adding the image through the CSS. If you look at the code I added you can see I am referencing url('<your image>') which adds your image as a background image. Read through the links I added in my answer they should help you understand better